# jQuery - update image url only folder

Tags: jquery, jquery-attributes

How can I update, Image URL only some part of it...

For Eg: I have 2 folders, if images coming from lenovo folder, I want change that folder to samsung

`<img src="images/lenovo/abc.jpg">` to `<img src="images/samsung/abc.jpg">`

Comment: $("img").attr('src').replace("lenovo","samsung");

Comment: Sorry **@yjs**... , its not working :(

Comment: You have code written? an existing code?

Comment: not existing... its new code

Comment: Get source and split it and replace second index of folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
$("img").each(function() {
var imgURL = $(this).attr('src');
if(imgURL.lastIndexOf('/')>6) {
imgURL = imgURL.replace("images/lenovo","images/samsung");
}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/lenovo/abc.jpg"><img src="images/xyz.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi **@yjs**.. it is working only if I have one image... please check the fiddle
https://fiddle.jshell.net/5vqsrgvx/1/

Comment: Now both solutions are there...you can prefer which to take!

Comment: Thanks **@yjs**.. it is working as expected... Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Take the current `src` of `img` and the use `replace()` to replace to update `src`. You can do it like below. Hope this will help you.

```
$(function () {
    var img = $("img");

    img.each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');

        if (src.indexOf('lenovo/') > -1) {
            $(this).attr('src', src.replace("lenovo", "samsung"));
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi **@Azim**... it is also working only if I have one image...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/5vqsrgvx/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check if the src-attribute contains 'lenovo'.

If it does, then replace it.

```
$(function() {
  var src = $('img:first').attr('src');
  var needle = 'lenovo';
  var altDirectory = 'samsung';
  var rep;

  if (src.search(needle) > -1) {
    rep = src.replace(needle, altDirectory);

    $('img:first').attr('src', rep);
  }       
});
```

Live-Demo:
http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/QyNJEp